# Getting a custom domain to behave with React on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, cname

I've followed all of the guides for directing a custom domain to a Github project page on both the Github end and the DNS's end. The Github Pages hosting for the project was working before the custom domain, but now either nothing works or just the normal Github Pages works, but not the custom domain.

I've tried moving everything around, renaming `CNAME` files, everything has had time to propagate, it *should* be working, but I'm at a loss for what to do. I've tried putting the `CNAME` file both in the `master` branch and the `gh-pages` branch. I've tried setting the `CNAME` either by hand in the file or automatically in the repo settings. All of this to no avail.

I can tell that it should be working because when I visit the custom domain it is definitely pointing to Github as it returns a 404 with no page found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent several hours pulling my hair out over this issue and figured I'd post the solution in the case someone else came across it as well.

The simple issue is that when `react-scripts build` runs, it ignores the `CNAME` file in the root directory and completely overwrites anything in the `build/` directory which in turn completely overwrites the `gh-pages` branch, so adding CNAME to that will solve the problem temporarily: until the next time you push.

The solution is extraordinarily simple: **move `CNAME` from `/` to `/public`.** `react-scripts` will recognize this as a static file to be served, just like a favicon and will always copy it to the `gh-pages` repo and include it in the build without you having to manually do it everytime you deploy.

Comment: My issue was that the PUBLIC_URL env variable was had my repo listed as a subdirectory of itself and I was able to automate a fix by removing the "/repo_name" from the end of the `homepage: ...` property in my package.json

Comment: @Nigh7Sh4de removing "/repo_name" from the homepage url was the fix for me after many trials. Thank you for commenting this.