# ReactJS app deployed on GitHub pages does not work with custom domain set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, github-pages

App works perfectly fine when it's deployed on `https://github.io/architect_portfolio` (when custom domain is not set). When it's deployed to `https://architect.mszanowski.pl`, all I can see is a blank white page.

[image]
[image]

What can I do to make it working? I think it has something to do with `architect_portfolio` part in assets urls.

To deploy it on custom domain I did following:

1. add CNAME `mszan.github.io.` record to my `architect.mszanowski.pl` subdomain,
2. update my `package.json` `homepage` and `name` values:

```
  "homepage": "https://architect.mszanowski.pl",
  "name": "architect_portfolio",
```

3. made a commit to master branch,
4. run `gh-pages -d build`

Repo: https://github.com/mszan/architect_portfolio

Another repo of working React app deployed on [custom domain](https://aestral.mszanowski.pl/) which is working fine: https://github.com/mszan/aestral_portfolio

Answer (score 2):

Your second repo that works fine have [CNAME](https://github.com/mszan/aestral-portfolio/blob/gh-pages/CNAME) file in gh-pages branch which contains the custom domain who github reads for custom domains mapping. While the repo that does not work in your case don't have this file in your gh-pages branch.

Solution:

```
Add CNAME file to /public dir
```

For details please consult [getting-a-custom-domain-to-behave-with-react-on-github-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609288/getting-a-custom-domain-to-behave-with-react-on-github-pages).